# rails-api:render json multiple values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have a model

```
class Banner < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :title, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  validates :description, length: { maximum: 200 }

  belongs_to :document

  def img_url
    document.medium_url
  end
end
```

and serializer

```
class BannerSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :title, :description, :img_url, :document_id
end
```

When I'm using `render json: Banner.all`, it response correctly (has "img_url" in the responding

```
{
"banners": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "This is title of banner",
      "description": "This is long description...",
      "img_url": "http://localhost:3000//system/documents/attachments/000/000/023/medium/one-piece.jpg?1459601536",
      "document_id": 23
    }
  ]
}
```

But when I want to return with other object by using.
example:

```
render json: {
      banners: Banner.all,
      blogs: Blog.all,
      partners: Partner.all
    }
```

The responding don't exist "img_url" (it don't use Serializer).

Please help.

Comment: What if you'd use `Blog.all.to_json`?

Comment: It don't include img_url too, beside that, the value of  banners become to string

Comment: Ok. what about using `as_json`?

Comment: `Blog.all.as_json` is the same with `Blog.all` (the responding is json object, but don't include img_url, I also try Blog.all.as_json(:serialize => BlogSerialize) but not success.

Comment: looking at docs and this link https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/issues/1204 something like this should work: `ActiveModel::SerializableResource.new(Banner.all).serializable_hash`

Comment: try `render json: BlogSerializer.new(Blog.all)`

Comment: @7urkm3n: It worked, thank you so much. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serializer has `new` method. That you can call it from controllers too.

```
render json: BlogSerializer.new(Blog.all)
```

For array, use ArraySerializer.
Example:

```
blogs = ActiveModel::ArraySerializer.new(blogs, each_serializer: ArticleSerializer)
```

Comment: I have test again, It worked on single value (example: `BlogSerializer.new(Blog.all.frist)`, but list don't work :(. BTW: thanks

Comment: probably, u have an issue somewhere. in my project it works.

Comment: I have found a solution by using ArraySerializer :) `ActiveModel::ArraySerializer.new(blogs, each_serializer: ArticleSerializer)` using for array

Comment: I have edited your comment, could you review that I can vote this anwer :)

Comment: With your help :), Thanks